# How to load two partial views when clicking a component?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to get two partial views to load when I click an item in a list.  I can get one to load, but I can't seem to find a good resource for how to accomplish what I'm trying to do.  I just want to click an item in the ProjectPanes view and have it load the partial views on ProjectData and ProgressArea based on the server name of the ProjectPane that was clicked.  Any help would be appreciated.

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MMCView";
}

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('click', '[id^=project]', function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                $('.mig-project').removeClass('selected').removeClass('low-opacity').addClass('full-opacity');
                $('#project-data').hide();
                $('#main-monitor').show();
            }
            else {
                $(this).addClass("selected").addClass('full-opacity').removeClass('low-opacity');
                $('.mig-project').not(this).removeClass("full-opacity").removeClass('selected').addClass("low-opacity");
                $('#project-data').load($(this).data("url"));
                $('#project-data').show();
                $('#main-monitor').hide();
            }
        })
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $(".slow-load").each(function(index, item) {
                var url = $(item).data("url");
                if (url && url.length > 0) {
                    $(item).load(url);
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
}

<h2 class="mig-header">Migration Monitoring Center</h2>

<div class="project-list slow-load" id="list-container" data-url="@Url.Action("ProjectPanes", "MMC")">
    <img src="loading.gif" />
</div>

<div class="data-container">
    <div class="container-left">
        <div id="project-data" data-url="@Url.Action("ProjectData", "MMC")"></div>
        <div class="monitor slow-load" id="main-monitor" data-url="@Url.Action("MainWindowMonitor", "MMC")"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-right">
        <div id="progress-area" data-url="@Url.Action("ProgressArea", "MMC")"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

MMCController.cs

```
public class MMCController : Controller
{
    //GET: MMC
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ProjectPanes()
    {
        MonitorData downloadedInfo = getCachedData();
        return PartialView("_ProjectPanes", downloadedInfo.MainPanel.OrderBy(o => o.Client).ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult ProjectData(string server)
    {
        MonitorData downloadedInfo = getCachedData();
        return PartialView("_ProjectData", downloadedInfo.Information.Where(x => x.ServerName == server));
    }

    public ActionResult MainWindowMonitor()
    {
        MonitorData downloadedInfo = getCachedData();
        return PartialView("_MainWindowMonitor", downloadedInfo.MonitorText);
    }

    public ActionResult ProgressArea(string server)
    {
        MonitorData downloadedInfo = getCachedData();
        IEnumerable<ProgressInfo> pi = downloadedInfo.progList.Where(x => x.ServerName == server);
        return PartialView("_ProgressArea", downloadedInfo.progList);
    }

    private MonitorData getCachedData()
    {
        var cache = HttpContext.Cache;
        if (cache["MonitorData"] == null)
        {
            cache.Add("MonitorData", LoadMonitorData(), null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
        }
        return (MonitorData)cache["MonitorData"];
    }

    private MonitorData LoadMonitorData()
    {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            string location = "http://MY-WEBAPI";
            string data = wc.DownloadString(new Uri(location));
            var deserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            MonitorData deserializedData = deserializer.Deserialize<MonitorData>(data);
            return deserializedData;
        }
    }
}
```

_ProjectPanes.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MMC_ASP.Models.Panel>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="mig-project" style="background-color:@item.BGColor" id="project-@item.Server" data-url="@Url.Action("ProjectData", "MMC", new { server = @item.Server })">
        <div class="client-name">@item.Client</div>
        <div class="source-target">@item.Project</div>
        <div class="server-name">@item.Server</div>
        <div class="error-count">@item.ErrCount</div>
    </div>
}
```

_ProgressArea.cshtml (placeholder in the @if statement)

```
@model MMC_ASP.Models.ProgressInfo

<div class="progress-container">
    <div class="progress-header">Last Updated</div>
    <div class="progress-updated">@DateTime.Now.ToString()</div>

        @if (Model != null)
        {
            <div class="progress-bar">@Model.PercentComplete.ToString();</div>
        }
        else
        {
            <div>EMPTY</div>
        }

    <div class="progress-button-container">
        <input type="button" value="Refresh" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `.click()` event is just showing/hiding elements, not 'loading' anything. You need to make an ajax call and update the DOM (but its a bit unclear what your 2 `.each()` functions are doing)

Comment: The 'else' on the .click event loads the project-data div.  the $(document).ready event loads every div with the .slow-load class (list-container and main-monitor) because these sections can't be loaded till I get a response from my webapi.  The query on the webapi takes about 30 seconds (hence, slow-load).  I did the .monitor class the same way, with .each, because I couldn't get it working with just .load("url").  Not really sure why...  Also, I should note, I'm a complete novice in Javascript and am just getting my feet wet in ASP.Net

Comment: There is some code here which is not making sense - you first `$.each()` is loading the `<div>` with `class="project-list"` and the `<div>` with `class="monitor"` (the both have `class="slow-load"`). The the 2nd `$.each()` is again loading the `<div>` with `class="monitor"` so your doing it twice. Then in your partial you have a `<div>` with `name="project-@item.Server"` which is not a valid attribute. But I'm not sure I understand just what it is you want to load when and how.

Comment: Oops...I removed the bit that loads `monitor` twice.  And for the `name`, I changed it to `id` instead and updated the jQuery to match.  What I'm trying to do is load the `progress-area` div AFTER the `slow-load` components are loaded.  The reason is that loading one of those (the ProjectPanes or MainWindowMonitor actions on the MMC controller) will call a WebAPI that runs a database query that takes 20-30 seconds.  The info returned will be used in all the components for the page, and is managed with the http cache so it only has to be retrieved once for the whole page.  Does that clarify?

Comment: You should be using a class name, not an `id` attribute - e.g. `$(document).on('click', '.mig-project', function () { ...`. Which part is not working?